# Hosting multiple MEAN stack apps on one VPS

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, amazon-ec2, mean-stack

I am learning how to develop MEAN stack applications and have gotten as far as deploying an app to an AWS EC2 instance running Ubuntu. Everything works, but I'm wondering if there is a way to host multiple apps on separate "directories".

So for example:

- **domain.com/app1/#/** would serve the index view for the first app
- **domain.com/app2/#/** would do the same for the second app

I know I could do something like this by writing the necessary routes into a single app.js file, but I'm really looking for a way to keep **app1** and **app2** as separated as possible.

Is this even possible? Or are Node apps only suited to live alone at the root of its deployment location?

Comment: Would something like nginx as a reverse proxy be acceptable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As above. Nginx will do the job. Something like this for each app:

```
server {
listen 80;

server_name example.com;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
}
}
```

More reading here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Am I able to use Nginx and my node apps all on the same EC2 instance? I should have also mentioned that I'm currently using an AWS Load Balancer as well to handle my SSL.

Comment: @WilliamThomas yes you can.

Comment: So I assume in that case, the domain would be resolving to the load balancer (possibly over TLS), which would privately hit the EC2 instance's Nginx server, which would route the request to the proper app on localhost. Is that correct?